# How to implement a custom error page in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, custom-error-pages

I want to implement a custom error page which shows my own error message instead of showing default error message.

so i have made some changes in web.config file. here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Account/Login">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.cshtml" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ShoppersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.Shoppers.csdl|res://*/Context.Shoppers.ssdl|res://*/Context.Shoppers.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Shoppers;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ShoppersEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.Shoppers.csdl|res://*/Context.Shoppers.ssdl|res://*/Context.Shoppers.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Shoppers;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

The following is my Error.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Home | E-Shopper</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/price-range.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Content/images/ico/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="~/Content/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="~/Content/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="~/Content/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="~/Content/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png" />
</head>
<!--/head-->
<body>
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="logo-404">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><img src="~/Content/images/home/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content-404">
            <img src="~/Content/images/404/404.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            <h1><b>OPPS!</b> We Couldn’t Find this Page</h1>
            <p>Uh... So it looks like you brock something. The page you are looking for has up and Vanished.</p>
            <h2><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Bring me back Home</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/price-range.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my error page is stored in views folder and in that shared folder.
Please help me to show custom error page.

Comment: i am getting a runtime error called "An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. "

Comment: Use Visual Studio debug mode, post unhandled exception you have get there. Also `defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml"` is not a right thing to call cshtml file, you need to define error controller then using virtual path to call custom error action method (e.g. `defaultRedirect="~/Error"`).

Comment: Thank you. I have done it by adding new controller called ErrorController and kept one method in it. That method calling my customErrror page. Now its working for the 404 error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From given `web.config` file, seems that these lines triggering second exception while returning custom error page:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.cshtml" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error.cshtml" />
</customErrors>
```

Since `defaultRedirect` attribute only accepts either absolute path to a HTML file or virtual/relative path to a controller action method, direct absolute path to a CSHTML file is inappropriate due to existence of Razor codes inside it which should be transformed to HTML by the server using an action method.

The issue can be solved by creating a controller class with a default action method like this (I assumed target error page exists inside /Views/Shared directory):

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Then, replace wrong path in `defaultRedirect` attribute with correct virtual path:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" >
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error" />
</customErrors>
```

PS: You can implement custom error pages for status codes other than 404 by adding action methods that include `Response.StatusCode = [HTML status code]` inside `ErrorController`.